# How to run the same Azure DevOps pipeline with different library variables - without cloning?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a reasonably complex release pipeline in Azure DevOps that releases a number of Azure apps, a database etc.

Each step is genericised using a library variable for the environment. For example:

[image]

But library variables are linked to a release or a selection of stages.

Currently I have to clone the entire pipeline and link a new library variable group in the clone to publish a different environment, but this is heavy on unwanted duplication and maintenance.

How can I run the same release pipeline with different library variables?

If I could do this, it would be possible to have a release for a given branch, for example, but I cannot see a way to do it.

Comment: You're explaining what you're currently doing, but not why. What is the driver that is making you clone your release? Why are you not using stages for each environment? You need to explain what your release structure looks like in more detail, ideally with YAML snippets (or for classic pipelines, screenshots).

Comment: Can you make your pipeline into a template and then you can use that in different pipelines with different variables? It's not exactly what you want, but it would provide a single point of change for any pipeline updates. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

At of this time, it is not supported to select which variable groups to use when you create a release.

If you only have one or several variables, I think **you can use pipeline variables instead of variable groups, so that you can update them at release time.** Here are the detailed steps:

1. Go to your pipeline editing page and select "Variables" tab. Click "Add" to add a variable. Then check the option "Settable at release time".
   [image]
2. Try re-create your release. You will find the variables defined in #1 and you can edit them before create the release.
   [image]

If you have many variables, I suggest you try to change the structure of your pipeline to make it more suitable for deployment to multiple environments. As Daniel said, you can use stages for each environment, and then use the variable group in stages scope.